# $templateCache.get returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
$http.get('template/alert.html', {
    cache: $templateCache
});
$scope.clickedButton = function () {
    console.log($templateCache.info()); // <-- Object {id: "templates", size: 1}
    console.log($templateCache.get('alert.html')); // <-- undefined
    console.log($templateCache.get('template/alert.html')); // <-- undefined
};
```

So I am trying to aquire the html, put it into the cache and then console.log out the contents of the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$http.get('template/alert.html', {
    cache: true
}).then(function(resp){
    $templateCache.put('template/alert.html', resp.data)
});
$scope.clickedButton = function () {
    console.log($templateCache.info()); // <-- Object {id: "templates", size: 1}
    console.log($templateCache.get('template/alert.html')); // <-- response
};
```

This might work for you

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it using [$templateRequest](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/api/ng/service/$templateRequest):

```js
$templateRequest(
  'template/alert.html'
);
$scope.clickedButton = function () {
  console.log($templateCache.info()); // <-- Object {id: "templates", size: 1}
  console.log($templateCache.get('template/alert.html')); // <-- response
};
```